# redirect to an external url on form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, external-url

i have a form which on submit should redirect to an external URL to perform some action with my form  data, as well as remain on the home page after successful submission. i used redirection, but this will make my second option possible, but not my first one. Please help..

Answer (score 2):

You have different possibilities here. The first possibility is to set the `action` attribute of the form directly to the external url and add a `returnurl` hidden input parameter. When the form is submitted it will POST data to the external url to process and when it finishes processing the external url will use the `returnurl` parameter to redirect back to your home page.

Another possibility is to call the external url in your POST action using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to send data for processing and return the same view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeViewModel model)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var values = new NameValueCollection 
        {
            { "param1", model.Property1 },
            { "param2", model.Property2 },
        };
        // send values for processing to the external url
        var result = client.UploadValues("http://externalurl.com", values);
        // TODO: analyze result
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: just for info, i can see  same answer in [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1899157.aspx?MVC+Post+Redirect)  post by @budugu with variable names changed

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually program for this. For example you can pass a returnUrl parameter (e.g. via the query string) to the second page and that page will be in charge of reading this parameter and perform a redirect of its own.